# WinForms distorted font

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I have a WinForms application that I build on my Win10 PC and the app is meant to run on another Win10 machine. Problem is that the fonts get distorted on the other machine. The first picture is from my PC and the second is from the other PC. The main problem is that it is hard to distinguish the number 6 and 8. Screenshots are from the DataGridView component but it is the same for basically every label in the app. I have not changed the font from the default *Microsoft Sans Serif; 8,25pt*. Any idea what could be wrong?

[image: Original font]
[image: Distorted font]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this problem started with Windows 8.

**Solution 1 found:**

Add a manifest by going to to Project > Add New Item > Application Manifest File.

For Visual Studio 2015 and above, you can simply uncomment this code:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

In older versions of Visual Studio, you need to add this code yourself as it won't be in the manifest automatically.

**Solution 2 :**

The problem must come from the difference in screen resolution.
In this case you have to change the window scaling mode.
By default, winform windows adjust their scaling for font size.

Property:
AutoScaleMode ==> Font

Do several tests by modifying this value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Go the the Forms designer, then select your Form (by clicking at its title bar)
2. Press F4 to open the Properties window, then locate the AutoScaleMode property
3. Change it from Font (default) to Dpi.

   ```
   static class Program
   {
       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
          if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
              SetProcessDPIAware();

           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           Application.Run(new MainForm());
     }

      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
      private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
    }
   ```